# Google Cloud Build Step Logs Not Viewable in Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-console

I am not able to view Google Cloud Build logs in the console. For each step that I click on I cannot see the associated logs in the Build Log window on the right (see picture). This occurs with both the Build Summary and each detail step. The only way to view these logs is to click View Raw, but that is only a great workaround.

[image: Cloud Build Console Screenshot]

Another issue is that each build step status (Success/Failure) is only populated at the end of the entire build process, as opposed to updating after each step.

Is anybody also experiencing this or have suggestions to rememdy this issue? My browser is Google Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: I also have to wait for the end of the build process to see the success/failure marks of all steps.   For not seeing the logs as they update ... I'll make a guess ... I suspect that the browser is making a WebSocket connection to Google to stream in the log outputs.  Are you VPN or otherwise connected to a private network that may restrict WebSocket connections?  Can you access the GCP Cloud Build console from the Public Internet and see if the logs show up?

Comment: @Kolban thank you for the comment! I am not connected to a VPN or a private network. However, I did notice that I am able to view each step's Build Log when I switch over to Safari, so this must be an issue with Chrome.

Comment: Thats a great clue.  The next thing I would suggest is to create a new Chrome Profile ... basically create a new instance of Chrome that has none of the plugins that you have in your default Chrome.  I want to see if you have a Chrome plugin that is interfering with the activities.

Comment: @Kolban that did it! I created a new blank Chrome profile with no extensions and I am now able to view the Build Logs in the console! I'm not sure which extension/plugin is the culprit, but I'll slowly add 1 at a time to this new Chrome profile and report back if I find anything, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experience shows that there can be adverse interactions between Chrome Plugins and a variety of websites that have rich content or streaming (such as Google's Console).  If something seems odd, try and create a new Chrome profile or try running in incognito mode and see if that resolves the issue.  If it does, you can incrementally add (or remove) the plugins until you find the one that is causing problems.  If you do find the culprit plugin, consider posting that as a comment to others on what you find.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs#viewing_build_logs), if you’re storing your build logs in logging, you won’t be able to see them in the cloud build page, instead you will be able to see them in the Logging page(i.e. Operations logging).

To view the build in Cloud Build page in the Cloud Console, if your build logs are present in the Google-created Cloud Storage bucket, grant the Project Viewer role on the project but if your build logs are in a user-specified Cloud Storage bucket, grant the Storage Object Viewer role. And for more information, consider looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs#viewing_build_logs).

Your second point is an expected behaviour, please look [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/view-build-results#step_status_and_build_status).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But I noticed that without changing any roles, I am able to view the build step logs in Safari. So I don't think it's an issue of permissions. In fact, I do notice some text in the Build Log window but it is entirely compressed in the top of the window and it's not readable (you can see the small grey strip of text at the top).

Answer (score 0):

Adding on Kolban's answer above, one of the Chrome extensions that interfered is Imagus. Uninstalling / disabling it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another Chrome extension that seems to cause the problem is "Dark Mode". My version is 0.4.2 on Chrome version 96.0.4664.110 and disabling this and refreshing the Build Detail page restored the build log listing.